# Convert set of Dates to End of Month Date

Tags: sql, oracle

Using Oracle SQL, how can I transform a set of dates to the date for the end of that month? Example below:

```
  Date        Amount
18/05/18        10
24/05/18        40
30/05/18        60

  Date        Amount
31/05/18       110
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply apply `last_day` (if there's a time part you must apply `trunc` to remove it):

```
TRUNC(LAST_DAY(datecol))
```

Comment: if `datecol` contains time part; we, probably, want to truncate it `TRUNC(LAST_DAY(datecol))`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: Of course, I tend to forget that Oracle's `date` is actually a `timestamp` :-)